# @typescript-eslint/member-ordering error seems incorrect

Tags: typescript-eslint

I am trying to figure out why ES-Lint says "Member `expectStatusCodeToBe` should be declared before member `statusCode`" in the following code:

```js
export interface IHttpResponse {
  get statusCode(): HttpStatusCode;

  expectStatusCodeToBe(statusCode: HttpStatusCode): void;
}
```

I have defined the member types so all methods should be declared AFTER getters.  The only place this is happening is within interfaces, so I can only assume something is different about them.

Here is how the rule is configured:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
  "error",
  {
    "default": {
      "memberTypes": [
        // Fields
        "public-static-field",
        "protected-static-field",
        "private-static-field",
        "#private-static-field",

        "public-decorated-field",
        "protected-decorated-field",
        "private-decorated-field",

        "public-instance-field",
        "protected-instance-field",
        "private-instance-field",
        "#private-instance-field",

        "public-abstract-field",
        "protected-abstract-field",

        "public-field",
        "protected-field",
        "private-field",
        "#private-field",

        "static-field",
        "instance-field",
        "abstract-field",

        "decorated-field",

        "field",

        // Static initialization
        "static-initialization",

        // Constructors
        "public-constructor",
        "protected-constructor",
        "private-constructor",

        "constructor",

        // Index signature
        "signature",
        "call-signature",

        // Accessors
        "public-static-accessor",
        "protected-static-accessor",
        "private-static-accessor",
        "#private-static-accessor",

        "public-decorated-accessor",
        "protected-decorated-accessor",
        "private-decorated-accessor",

        "public-instance-accessor",
        "protected-instance-accessor",
        "private-instance-accessor",
        "#private-instance-accessor",

        "public-abstract-accessor",
        "protected-abstract-accessor",

        "public-accessor",
        "protected-accessor",
        "private-accessor",
        "#private-accessor",

        "static-accessor",
        "instance-accessor",
        "abstract-accessor",

        "decorated-accessor",

        "accessor",

        // Getters
        "public-static-get",
        "protected-static-get",
        "private-static-get",
        "#private-static-get",

        "public-decorated-get",
        "protected-decorated-get",
        "private-decorated-get",

        "public-instance-get",
        "protected-instance-get",
        "private-instance-get",
        "#private-instance-get",

        "public-abstract-get",
        "protected-abstract-get",

        "public-get",
        "protected-get",
        "private-get",
        "#private-get",

        "static-get",
        "instance-get",
        "abstract-get",

        "decorated-get",

        "get",

        // Setters
        "public-static-set",
        "protected-static-set",
        "private-static-set",
        "#private-static-set",

        "public-decorated-set",
        "protected-decorated-set",
        "private-decorated-set",

        "public-instance-set",
        "protected-instance-set",
        "private-instance-set",
        "#private-instance-set",

        "public-abstract-set",
        "protected-abstract-set",

        "public-set",
        "protected-set",
        "private-set",
        "#private-set",

        "static-set",
        "instance-set",
        "abstract-set",

        "decorated-set",

        "set",

        // Methods
        "public-static-method",
        "protected-static-method",
        "private-static-method",
        "#private-static-method",

        "public-decorated-method",
        "protected-decorated-method",
        "private-decorated-method",

        "public-instance-method",
        "protected-instance-method",
        "private-instance-method",
        "#private-instance-method",

        "public-abstract-method",
        "protected-abstract-method",

        "public-method",
        "protected-method",
        "private-method",
        "#private-method",

        "static-method",
        "instance-method",
        "abstract-method",

        "decorated-method",

        "method"
      ],
      "order": "alphabetically-case-insensitive"
    }
  }
]
```